# "JAVA Parse Exception" error in Qualimap after MacOSX upgrade

Tags: java, maven, error-handling

I recently upgraded my MacOSX system to Catalina and several files were placed automatically into "Relocated items" folder on my Desktop. I recently tried to run the following code which had previously worked:

```
qualimap bamqc -bam Sample1_sorted.bam -c -outdir QualiMap/Sample1_sorted
```

and received the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.bioinfo.ngs.qc.qualimap.main.NgsSmartMain
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
```

I have seen many other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874590/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-cli-parseexception) related to this error but am unsure how to even go about trying some of the suggested solutions. I do not work directly with some of the applications/files mentioned in these forums, such as JAVA, Maven, AppAssembler, and the pom.xml file (I could not even find that file). As a result, I wished to ask about this error from the perspective of a biologist using qualimap.

How can I fix this error (with little knowledge of the above applications/files)? I can certainly work with these applications/files, but I would probably need more detailed/basic/low-level advice on how to access and modify them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what qualimap is a java application someone else wrote. I would raise a ticket with whomever wrote this app.